# Why do my Flask psycopg2 app returns sync error with server?

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, psycopg2

I'm facing issue with my flask app that uses psycopg2 for postgres. Sometimes my API returns 500 server error in which it said in the log file:

```
[SQL: SELECT gallery.id AS gallery_id, gallery.caption AS gallery_caption, gallery.image AS gallery_image, gallery.created_date AS gallery_created_date, gallery.updated_date AS gallery_updated_date 
FROM gallery ORDER BY gallery.id]
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/e3q8)
[UID:1549][94744] Child process with pid: 98159 was killed by signal: 15, core dump: 0
[ERROR] [UID:1549][97456] wsgiAppHandler pApp->start_response() return NULL.
/home/myapp/virtualenv/api/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py:873: FSADeprecationWarning: SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS adds significant overhead and will be disabled by default in the future.  Set it to True or False to suppress this warning.
  'SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS adds significant overhead and '
[2021-12-27 11:22:11,886] ERROR in app: Exception on /gallery/find-all [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/myapp/virtualenv/api/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1803, in _execute_context
    cursor, statement, parameters, context
  File "/home/myapp/virtualenv/api/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 732, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
psycopg2.OperationalError: lost synchronization with server: got message type "G", length 1935229752


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/myapp/virtualenv/api/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2073, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/myapp/virtualenv/api/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1518, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/home/myapp/virtualenv/api/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_cors/extension.py", line 165, in wrapped_function
    return cors_after_request(app.make_response(f(*args, **kwargs)))
  File "/home/myapp/virtualenv/api/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_cors/extension.py", line 165, in wrapped_function
    return cors_after_request(app.make_response(f(*args, **kwargs)))
  File "/home/myapp/virtualenv/api/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1516, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/home/myapp/virtualenv/api/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1502, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**req.view_args)
  File "/home/myapp/api/myapplication/auth.py", line 32, in decorated
    return f(auth_data, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/myapp/api/myapplication/gallery.py", line 71, in fetch_image
    image_data = Gallery.query.filter().order_by(Gallery.id).all()
  File "/home/myapp/virtualenv/api/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 2759, in all
    return self._iter().all()
  File "/home/myapp/virtualenv/api/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 2897, in _iter
    execution_options={"_sa_orm_load_options": self.load_options},
  File "/home/myapp/virtualenv/api/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1692, in execute
    result = conn._execute_20(statement, params or {}, execution_options)
  File "/home/myapp/virtualenv/api/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1614, in _execute_20
    return meth(self, args_10style, kwargs_10style, execution_options)
  File "/home/myapp/virtualenv/api/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 326, in _execute_on_connection
    self, multiparams, params, execution_options
  File "/home/myapp/virtualenv/api/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1491, in _execute_clauseelement
    cache_hit=cache_hit,
  File "/home/myapp/virtualenv/api/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1846, in _execute_context
    e, statement, parameters, cursor, context
  File "/home/myapp/virtualenv/api/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2027, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    sqlalchemy_exception, with_traceback=exc_info[2], from_=e
  File "/home/myapp/virtualenv/api/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 207, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "/home/myapp/virtualenv/api/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1803, in _execute_context
    cursor, statement, parameters, context
  File "/home/myapp/virtualenv/api/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 732, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) lost synchronization with server: got message type "G", length 1935229752
```

This API just fetch all the data from the table and returns them to the client. The table only have max 12 rows and contains base-64 string of image data. However, this also happens at other API that fetch a single data from other table and returns only text data-type.

These APIs works well in my local development env but went error in production (CPanel shared hosting)

Comment: How did you install psycopg2 on the server?

Comment: I created python app and uploaded my flask code there, then installed the psycopg2 along with other libraries via ssh using pip install command

Comment: Did you `pip install psycopg2`, `pip install psycopg2-binary` or ...?

Comment: I installed the psycopg2-binary actually, because with psycopg2 (non-binary) it seems not to be working well

Comment: You probably need to `pip install psycopg2` then.  It's possible the pre-compiled version is not compatible with something on your server.

Comment: I did actually, I tried psycopg2 first before psycopg2-binary and it gave me weird errors (i lost the log for this). And today I just retried using it and still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

One possible scenario is your SQLAlchemy engine/session instance is shared between
main process and worker process.

When Flask is started, a main process is created. Then the main process spawn sub process/ threads.

This happened to me when I do db operations before the sub process started.

For example, the following code could cause this problem:

```py
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
db = SQLAlchemy()
db.init_app(app)

def do_something_before_worker_start():
    db.session.query(...)
    db.session.remove()

do_something_before_worker_start()
```

As the `db.session` instance is initialized on the main process. Even when you `.remove()` the session, the connection is not removed but back to the connection pool.
When a worker process is created, this "dead" connection is randomly picked up when you call a API that involves database operations.

That's why the database error randomly happen.

If you must do something outside the worker scope, You can disable the connection pool.

```py
import sqlalchemy
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_ENGINE_OPTIONS"] = {
    "poolclass": sqlalchemy.pool.NullPool,
}
db = SQLAlchemy()
db.init_app(app)
```